# viewModelScope.launch with the viewModel variable onDestory() not working

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

The following coe prints only "onDestory", not "launch". But if I modify the code like the second block, then "launch" is printed. Why is that? Is class member variable destroyed before `onDestroy()`?

```
  lateinit var viewModel: ArticleViewModel;

  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this)[ArticleViewModel::class.java];
  ....

  override fun onDestroy()
  {
    super.onDestroy()
    Log.d("stack", "onDestroy");

    viewModel.viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO)
    {
      Log.d("stack", "launch");
    }
  }
```

Modification

```
  override fun onDestroy()
  {
    super.onDestroy()
    Log.d("stack", "onDestroy");
    val vm = ViewModelProvider(this)[ArticleViewModel::class.java];
    vm.viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO)
    {
      Log.d("stack", "launch");
    }
  }
```

Comment: The viewmodel scope will call onCleared after onDestroy so i think this approach doesnt work.  If you need to create some job in background, maybe you can create a workmanager to do the task.  Viewmodel scope -> https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel?hl=es

Comment: @ManuelMato I was trying to save the state of the activity to the Room database which throws an exception when called in the main thread. I changed the code to `CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO)` and it seemed to work, when the activity was the second activity. But when it is the main activity, `onDestory` does not seem to be called when pressing the back button, so my state saving code is not called.

Comment: Because when you press the back button, the activity is not destroyed, is in the onStop lifecycle.  If you want to destroy the activity when on back, then is necessary to override the onBackPressed method and call finish()

Comment: @ManuelMato what you say about onStop state, would be true (in most cases) if you press the HOME button. A simple application with a single Activity usually gets destroyed after you press the BACK button. All this said with a *most cases* disclaimer. Different Android implementations behave differently based on how aggressive the system is with resources. Regardless of this, +1 that if you implement onBackPressed you have more control over what is running when pressing back. Saving to database could happen inside onBackPressed, waiting for it to finish and then finish the activity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

my answer below is based on the assumption that your Activity is finishing and not being recreated (which is what would happen in a configuration change for example)

The viewModelScope is a special scope that follows the lifecycle of the ViewModel. Which means that if the viewModel.onCleared() is called then the viewModelScope is being canceled. Side note: if you try to launch a coroutine in a canceled scope, nothing will happen.

Now take a look at the [ViewModel Lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#lifecycle)
If your activity is finishing, then the onCleared() will get called soon after the onDestroy of your Activity.

Coming to your code, I think that the job you are trying to start, is never getting started because your onCleared is called before the Dispatchers.IO manages to start the job

The second block of code (and I am making a guess here) is probably creating another instance of the ViewModel that somehow manages to outlive the destruction of the activity, since it receives no activity lifecycle calls (nothing else is happening after onDestroy).
This is probably a bug. In my opinion you shouldn't be allowed to request a viewmodel from the provider while inside onDestroy

Comment: Yeah, I had pressed the back button to close the activity. Come to think of it, the activity could end before doing the thing in "launcg". Why didn't I realise that...